# Visual-Studio-Code python imports and classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

When using VS Code, I noticed things like...
    from multiprocessing import Pool, Value

Do not work... I can from multiprocessing import pool, then dig into that to get the Pool class, but even if it is valid Python, I cannot seem to import the class directly with intellisense.

In addition, because it doesn't understand why I'm just importing a class, all the rest the autocomplete falls right on its face. Even if it is valid code.

I've searched for settings, messed with some knobs, and editor tweaks, but I just cannot get VSCode to import classes from any module. Seems that the class isn't in multiprocessing but a package below it, and it isn't drilling in.

Comment: Feel free to report a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

> from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

Pool doesn't exist in the multiprocessing package but it exists in the pool subpackage under multiprocessing. 
The directory structure is

```
multiprocessing/
    __init__.py
    pool.py
```

When you do

> from multiprocessing import pool

You are actually trying to import from `__init__.py` which doesn't have the Pool class, pool.py has the Pool class. 
Hope this helps.

reference - [Python multiprocessing source code on github](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/multiprocessing)